# Angularjs rails-api ng-token-auth password edit callback fails to create session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rails-api

Working with [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) and [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) am having an issue with signing in user after processing by DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#edit success response.

Should the auth_headers get created automatically after the password request link has been clicked and the link validated?

After successful processing and the user is issued a new token the cookie does not seem to be created.

The user was created with email as the provider.

I thought it was something to do with the updateHeadersFromResponse guard but after testing different scenarios I could not get the cookie set.

Using:

"ng-token-auth": "~0.0.24"
'devise_token_auth', '0.1.32.beta5'

Engine mount

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'api/v1/auth'
```

config:

```
$authProvider.configure
   apiUrl: '/api/v1'
   camelcase: true
   passwordResetSuccessUrl: "http://#{window.location.host}/passwords/new"
```

logs

```
I, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.777006 #9165]  INFO -- : Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
I, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.777336 #9165]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"config"=>"default", "redirect_url"=>"http://localhost:9000/passwords/new", "reset_password_token"=>"3jFKJQf7kvs9-zfF9wnc"}
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.778220 #9165] DEBUG -- : Unpermitted parameters: config, redirect_url
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.780147 #9165] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "c9ca932cda8b75ac015400c0f68e574b068d508a3b5b0d7876dbc3499323efc2"]]
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.793581 #9165] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.833572 #9165] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = $1, "reset_password_sent_at" = $2, "confirmed_at" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["reset_password_token", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["confirmed_at", "2015-02-25 19:51:01.815839"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-25 19:51:01.822137"], ["id", 1]]
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.839142 #9165] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  COMMIT
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.912693 #9165] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.946934 #9165] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "reset_password_token" = $2, "confirmed_at" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["tokens", "{....}"], ["reset_password_token", "3jFKJQf7kvs9-zfF9wnc"], ["confirmed_at", "2015-02-25 19:51:01.932491"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-25 19:51:01.936220"], ["id", 1]]
D, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.968907 #9165] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  COMMIT
I, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.969659 #9165]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://localhost:9000/passwords/new#?client_id=zi5ihgfTaJDQ3tFukpVDfA&config=default&expiry=&reset_password=true&token=kL7diwIIKNuAX-NGEVhwDA&uid=jackson%40lodestonesocial.com
I, [2015-02-25T13:51:01.969929 #9165]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 192ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

I do see Cookie auth-headers in the request before the redirect.

```
  Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/v1/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fpasswords%2Fnew&reset_password_token=mb3nwTppyELyHwzi8ZD7
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:mousestats_vi=e0efc4fe54f55ac24932; s_fid=1511233B84249BCF-2A70FF9576CEA8FF; __atuvc=2%7C37; _ga=GA1.1.874460992.1415391225; auth_headers=%7B%22access-token%22%3A%22s5U7OQDrABl-MM0kQzGGEw%22%2C%22token-type%22%3A%22Bearer%22%2C%22client%22%3A%22kjx3B-9SaMXIxR__PM2A9A%22%2C%22expiry%22%3A%221426114814%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22jackson%40lodestonesocial.com%22%7D; currentConfigName=default
Host:localhost:9000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
config:default
redirect_url:http://localhost:9000/passwords/new
reset_password_token:mb3nwTppyELyHwzi8ZD7

Response Headers
cache-control:no-cache
connection:close
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Thu, 26 Feb 2015 00:01:25 GMT
location:http://localhost:9000/passwords/new#?client_id=5K0492gspvoxQkG2cDW_3w&config=default&expiry=&reset_password=true&token=fHmDzTN4hGpZTzrpZ0tfdQ&uid=jackson%40lodestonesocial.com
status:302 Found
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-request-id:0b96ae82-8a43-4cef-8f2a-2ca443b62ef6
x-runtime:0.222208
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue just now, I just overrode the `PasswordController`:

```
module Overrides
  class PasswordsController < DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController
    def resource_params
      params.permit(:your_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure you also config the route file accordingly:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    passwords: 'overrides/passwords'
}
```

Additionally for me, because I was modifying password reset, I had to modify my devise user model to use confirmable and added an e-mail configuration.

Hope that helps!